# How to infer the predicted class label from Spark MLlib computed raw score

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Reading the Spark Doc below

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-optimization.html

The sample code segment for binary classification prediction below:

```
    val model = new LogisticRegressionModel(
    Vectors.dense(weightsWithIntercept.toArray.slice(0,weightsWithIntercept.size - 1)),
    weightsWithIntercept(weightsWithIntercept.size - 1))

    // Clear the default threshold.
    model.clearThreshold()

   // Compute raw scores on the test set.
   val scoreAndLabels = test.map { point =>
   val score = model.predict(point.features)
   (score, point.label)
```

As you see model.prediction(point.features) return raw scores which are the margin of distances to hyperplane separations.

My question is:

(1) How can I know if the prediction class label is 0 or 1 based upon the above computed raw scores ?

Or

(2) How to infer the predicted class label (0, or 1) in this binary classification case from the above computed raw scores ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the threshold value is 0.5, thus when using the `BinaryClassificationMetrics`, it will give class label 0 if the score is < 0.5 and 1 if it is higher. So you can do the same to infer the class from the score.

Comment: How to get the optimal threshold which the algorithm determines to compute ROC curve ?

Comment: On the metrics object, you can get the scores by threshold for various metrics.. for instance: val f1Score = metrics.fMeasureByThreshold. Then you can iterate to find the best threshold details here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html